# Extract complete pixel values inside a geometry

Tags: polygon, javascript, google-earth-engine

I'm trying to write an earth engine script which extracts the pixel band values inside a polygon. (geometry)  Only for pixels completely within the polygon.  The polygons will be quite small. (field size)

I have looked through the docs, and searched for this, but am unable to find a solution.  Have only found statistical reductions.

```
// get the dates
var startDate = ee.Date.fromYMD(2018,1,1);
var endDate = ee.Date.fromYMD(2018,2,1);

// Create a geometry representing an export region.
var myGeometry = ee.Geometry.Polygon(
[[[-61.15985870361328, -32.94904673848672],
      [-61.152305603027344, -32.944797148619905],
      [-61.15659713745117, -32.9395388987784],
      [-61.16432189941406, -32.94378874137744]]]);



var landsatCollection = ee.ImageCollection("LANDSAT/LC08/C01/T1_SR");

// Filter image collection to dateRange of interest
var landsatDateCollection = ee.ImageCollection(landsatCollection
.filterDate(startDate,endDate));

//Filter to AOI.
var landsatAOI = ee.ImageCollection(landsatDateCollection
.filterBounds(myGeometry));

// Filter to image with least clouds
var landsatBestImage = ee.Image(landsatAOI
.sort('CLOUD_COVER')
.first());

// Load a landsat image and select three bands.
var landsatDownload = ee.Image(landsatBestImage)
.select(['B4', 'B5']);
```

---

```
/////////
//Added code that was improved after Jon's comments
/////////


// generate a new image containing lat/lon of the pixel and reproject it to Landsat projection
var coordsImage = ee.Image.pixelLonLat().reproject(landsatDownload.projection());

var joinedImage = coordsImage.addBands(landsatDownload);

var valuesList = joinedImage.reduceRegion({
  reducer: ee.Reducer.toList(4),
  geometry: myGeometry
}).values().get(0);

print(valuesList);
```

Jon's inspiration on the MODIS script allowed the modification above.  The **valuesList** now contains all the pixel information.

To see how to Export the data in **valuesList** to a CSV see

[Earth Engine convert list with coordinates and values into a feature collection for export](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/278607/earth-engine-convert-list-with-coordinates-and-values-into-a-feature-collection)

Comment: What is your expected output? You could do this pretty easily if you just wanted to export an image; just mask the image with a mask created by your polygons, then export at native resolution.

Comment: The idea is to extract the pixel centroid coordinates, and the value of B4, and B5. Later I will add the date image etc.

Comment: Here's an example for how to do it with a Modis image: https://code.earthengine.google.com/2acea4c7e2f39c372d95a1cd06547577

Comment: Also: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/google-earth-engine-developers/pixel$20coordinates%7Csort:relevance

Comment: Thanks Jon.  I'm exploring the code for modis to see if I can adapt it to landsat.  As is, it has an error which I can't find the reason to.  If I find what it is, I'll post back.  

The google group seems to be blocked due to spam, or malicious content.

Comment: Extracting the pixel centroids and band values sounds *exactly* like clipping the raster to the polygon areas, bands 4 and 5 and exporting it. There are number of tools for R (which seems to be where you want to use it) which can convert the raster to a table or dataframe - i.e. in the raster package.

Comment: I can do it in R.  I'm seeing if I can save a step and do the extraction before.  Leveraging on the power of the earth engine to have features from any place on the globe.  My R method requires me to download each sat image for each polygon, which take a lot of time and space.

Comment: @SeanRoulet can you please take a look at this question, it is related to this one. Thanks!
https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/294595/extract-pixel-values-for-multiple-polygons-and-images