# Earth Engine convert list with coordinates and values into a feature collection for export

Tags: javascript, export, google-earth-engine

I need to create a feature collection from a list containing coordinates and band values.  These are extracted from a landsat image as shown in this linked script.

[Extract complete pixel values inside a geometry](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/278533/extract-complete-pixel-values-inside-a-geometry)

I'm unable to find a solution in creating a feature collection.  Here is the tail end code.

```
var valuesList = joinedImage.reduceRegion({
  reducer: ee.Reducer.toList(4),
  geometry: myGeometry
}).values().get(0);

var feature = ee.Feature(null, valuesList);


// Wrap the Feature in a FeatureCollection for export.
var myFeatures = ee.FeatureCollection([feature]);


// Export the image, specifying scale and region.
Export.table.toDrive(myFeatures,
"data",
"myData",
"B4-B5", 
"CSV");
```

This doesn't work, because it is clearly the wrong way to create the feature collection.  I've tried to create it similar to Rodrigo E. Principe's solution of mapping a Feature Collection but I can't seem to create the initial feature collection to start with.

Comment: are you working in Argentina?

Comment: Any way to message privately?

Comment: yes, fitoprincipe82 at gmail =)

Comment: @RodrigoE.Principe can you please take a look at my question https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/294595/extract-pixel-values-for-multiple-polygons here. I am trying to do the exact same thing but with multiple geometries. It is really urgent if I can get some help on this. Thank you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
valuesList = ee.List(valuesList) // Cast valuesList

var myFeatures = ee.FeatureCollection(valuesList.map(function(el){
  el = ee.List(el) // cast every element of the list
  var geom = ee.Geometry.Point([ee.Number(el.get(0)), ee.Number(el.get(1))])
  return ee.Feature(geom, {'B4':ee.Number(el.get(2)), 'B5':ee.Number(el.get(3))})
}))

Map.addLayer(myFeatures) // see the result
Map.centerObject(myFeatures)

// Export the image, specifying scale and region.
Export.table.toDrive(myFeatures,
"data",
"myData",
"B4-B5", 
"CSV");
```

Comment: Any clue how I could include a "date" column in the above code snippet?