# Working with .geo of GEE in R

Tags: shapefile, r, google-earth-engine, geometry, sf

I am doing something similar to a [previous post on stack exchange](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/278607/earth-engine-convert-list-with-coordinates-and-values-into-a-feature-collection?answertab=votes#tab-top) regarding exporting data from GEE to csv. Once I have the .geo column, how do I work with it in R? I would like to create a shapefile as the final output.

Considering an exported csv as per the previous link called "test" where I have deleted the system:index column that is automatically generated.

```
test<-{data.frame(B4=c(0.2043, 0.2043, 0.2080), B5=c(0.2573, 0.2573, 0.2653), .geo=c('{"type":"Point","coordinates":[2.6631005755365273,50.90550594166401]}','{"type":"Point","coordinates":[2.6631904070649393,50.90550594166401]}',
'{"type":"Point","coordinates":[2.663280238593351,50.90550594166401]}'))}

df = st_as_sf(test, wkt = ".geo", crs = 4326)
```

I get this error
*Error in CPL_sfc_from_wkt(x) : OGR error*

I also tried this to modify the geometry structure

```
geonew= st_as_sfc(structure(as.character(test$.geo), class ="WKB"),EWKB=TRUE)
```

I got this error.
*Error in CPL_hex_to_raw(vapply(x, skip0x, USE.NAMES = FALSE, "")) :
char2int: unrecognized character in hex string*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These aren't WKT strings, they are GeoJSON strings.

I can't see a native converter in `sf` package, but you can do it with the `geojsonsf` package by adding a `geom` column and calling `st_as_sf`. You are left with both an `sf` geometry column and the source geoJSON column:

```
> library(geojsonsf)
> st_as_sf(data.frame(test, geom=geojson_sf(test$.geo)))
Simple feature collection with 3 features and 3 fields
geometry type:  POINT
dimension:      XY
bbox:           xmin: 2.663101 ymin: 50.90551 xmax: 2.66328 ymax: 50.90551
z_range:        zmin: NA zmax: NA
m_range:        mmin: NA mmax: NA
CRS:            EPSG:4326
      B4     B5
1 0.2043 0.2573
2 0.2043 0.2573
3 0.2080 0.2653
                                                                   .geo
1 {"type":"Point","coordinates":[2.6631005755365273,50.90550594166401]}
2 {"type":"Point","coordinates":[2.6631904070649393,50.90550594166401]}
3  {"type":"Point","coordinates":[2.663280238593351,50.90550594166401]}
                   geometry
1 POINT (2.663101 50.90551)
2  POINT (2.66319 50.90551)
3  POINT (2.66328 50.90551)
```

Comment: Thank you @Spacedman ! it works perfectly