# Export data from time-series image collection to a table in Google Earth Engine

Tags: remote-sensing, google-earth-engine, modis, time-series, nasa

On Google Earth Engine, I'd like to accomplish two tasks:

1. extract data from every pixel, across a time-series, within the given geometry bounds and save it as a table.
2. I need a column which prints the date of the image.

For the first part here is my code snippet (borrowed from : [Extract complete pixel values inside a geometry](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/278533/extract-complete-pixel-values-inside-a-geometry?noredirect=1&lq=1)) ---

```js
// the geometry bounds
var rectangle = ee.Geometry.Rectangle(96.01669, 18.52621, 96.04819, 18.49634);

//the time series dataset
var dataset = ee.ImageCollection("MODIS/006/MOD13Q1")
.filterDate('2000-01-01', '2000-03-31')
.filterBounds(rectangle)
.select('NDVI', 'SummaryQA');

// Sort the dataset
var sorteddataset = dataset.sort('system:time_start', true);

var first = sorteddataset.first();

// generate a new image containing lat/lon of the pixel and reproject 
// it to MODIS projection
var coordsImage = 
ee.Image.pixelLonLat().reproject(first.projection());

var joinedImage = coordsImage.addBands(first);

var valuesList = joinedImage.reduceRegion({
reducer: ee.Reducer.toList(4),
geometry: rectangle
}).values().get(0);

valuesList = ee.List(valuesList) // Cast valuesList

var myFeatures = ee.FeatureCollection(valuesList.map(function(el){
el = ee.List(el) // cast every element of the list
var geom = ee.Geometry.Point([ee.Number(el.get(0)), 
ee.Number(el.get(1))])
return ee.Feature(geom, {'NDVI':ee.Number(el.get(2)), 
'SummaryQA':ee.Number(el.get(3))})

}))

Export.table.toDrive(results,
"data",
"ndvi-testing",
"NDVI-SummaryQA", 
"CSV");
```

How do I modify the code to include the entire time-series instead of just the first image?
And how can I include a command that prints the image date? 
Below is the image of the table I get from the given code.
[image: example table that i get from the given code]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here is a modification of the first example from [this presentation about tables and vectors](https://docs.google.com/presentation/d/1D7rezUHPElCfYWHMRNBChHjbEv6nXDD8xnh7_YgyK6A/edit?usp=sharing).  Note that you can "transpose" the table if there are other properties in the points that are of interest:

```js
var rectangle = ee.Geometry.Rectangle(96.01669, 18.52621, 96.04819, 18.49634);
Map.centerObject(rectangle);
Map.addLayer(rectangle, {}, 'rectangle')

var dictionary = ee.Image.pixelLonLat().reduceRegion({
  reducer: ee.Reducer.toCollection(['longitude', 'latitude']), 
  geometry: rectangle, 
  scale: 250
});

var points = ee.FeatureCollection(dictionary.get('features'))
    .map(function(feature) {
      var lon = feature.get('longitude');
      var lat = feature.get('latitude');
      return ee.Feature(ee.Geometry.Point([lon, lat]), {
        'featureID': ee.Number(lon).multiply(1000).round().format('%5.0f')
            .cat('_')
            .cat(ee.Number(lat).multiply(1000).round().format('%5.0f'))
      });
    });
print('points', points)
Map.addLayer(points);

var dataset = ee.ImageCollection("MODIS/006/MOD13Q1")
  .filterDate('2000-01-01', '2000-03-31')
  .select('NDVI')
print('dataset', dataset)

var triplets = dataset.map(function(image) {
  return image.reduceRegions({
    collection: points, 
    reducer: ee.Reducer.first().setOutputs(image.bandNames()), 
    scale: 250,
  }).map(function(feature) {
    return feature.set({
      'imageID': image.id(),
      'timeMillis': image.get('system:time_start')
    })
  });
}).flatten();
print(triplets) 

var format = function(table, rowId, colId, rowProperty, colProperty) {
  var rows = table.distinct(rowId); 
  var joined = ee.Join.saveAll('matches').apply({
    primary: rows, 
    secondary: table, 
    condition: ee.Filter.equals({
      leftField: rowId, 
      rightField: rowId
    })
  });
  return joined.map(function(row) {
      var values = ee.List(row.get('matches'))
        .map(function(feature) {
          feature = ee.Feature(feature);
          return [feature.get(colId), feature.get(colProperty)];
        }).flatten();
      return row.select([rowId, rowProperty]).set(ee.Dictionary(values));
    });
};

var results = format(triplets, 'imageID', 'featureID', 'timeMillis', 'NDVI');
print(results)

// Note that there's a dummy feature in there for the points ('null').
var transpose = format(triplets, 'featureID', 'imageID', 'null', 'NDVI');
print(transpose)

Export.table.toDrive({
  collection: results, 
  description: 'foo', 
  fileNamePrefix: 'foo', 
  fileFormat: 'CSV'
});
```

https://code.earthengine.google.com/09ae70e7bce823b8fbe763601620c732