# Get image pixel centroids in Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine, image, centroids, feature-collection

I would like to create a feature collection consisting of the centroid points of the pixels in an image. The question of how to do this [has been asked before on Stack Exchange, but not actually answered.](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/308989/centroid-value-extraction-of-landsat-image-collection-in-google-earth-engine)

For example, suppose we have a single image such as the ESA 2009 global land cover. I crop this to the boder of the Republic of Congo:

```
var countries = ee.FeatureCollection('USDOS/LSIB_SIMPLE/2017');
var congo = countries.filter(ee.Filter.eq('country_na', 'Rep of the Congo'));

var dataset = ee.Image('ESA/GLOBCOVER_L4_200901_200912_V2_3').clip(congo);
```

With this data, how do I obtain a collection of points at the centroid of each pixel in the image? Converting the image to a feature collection does not seem to be the right approach, as this assigns polygons based on properties (not pixels).

Answer (score 0):

As it turns out, someone has answered this question before on Stack Exchange. See [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63453191/raster-to-point-conversion-how-to-convert-every-single-pixel-on-google-earth-e).